# javascript How to create multidimensional array with key and checkboxes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I need help to create array which to be passed via ajax to php page.

here is my html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.p_options').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(1).show();
    } else $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(0).hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.optschecks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.opts_qty {
  width: 50px;
}

.showerror,
.opts_qty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addtocart(id){
 arr = {};
 var error = 0;
 var checked = 0;
if ($('.p_options').length) {

  $('.p_options').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var num = $(this).next(".opts_qty").val();
      if (num !== '' && num > 0) {
        //info[id].push($(this).val());
        arr[id] = $(this).val();
        checked++;
        $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', '#fff');
      } else {
        $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', 'red');
        error++;
      }
      
    }
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

}
if(error < 1){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./shop/basket.php",
 data: { "product": id ,  'product_options':arr},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
 alert('success');
    }
});


}

}
</script>
<div class="inprd">Please select from options for Size
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value="S - 16 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> S - 16 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">    
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" M - 17mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> M - 17mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" L- 18 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> L- 18 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
</div>
<span class="add_to_cart_container ib"><button onclick="addtocart(this.id);" name="ring" id="2617" class="add_to_cart" price="52.00" type="button">Add to basket</button></span>
```

If you run the snippet you will see its working but out of the loop the array consist only ID + 1 selected option. If the customer selects more than 1 option it is not saved. How to add all selected options? AND something else I can not manage - how to add the quantity for each product option which is selected to the array?
Thank you for your help and time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an object to save your values you could use an array, like the example...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.p_options').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(1).show();
    } else $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(0).hide();
  })
});


function addtocart(id){
 arr = [];
 var error = 0;
 var checked = 0;
if ($('.p_options').length) {

  $('.p_options').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var num = $(this).next(".opts_qty").val();
      if (num !== '' && num > 0) {
        //info[id].push($(this).val());
        var object = {};
        object[''+$(this).val()] = num;
        arr.push(object);
        checked++;
        $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', '#fff');
      } else {
        $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', 'red');
        error++;
      }
      
    }
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

}
if(error < 1){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./shop/basket.php",
 data: { "product": id ,  'product_options':arr},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
 alert('success');
    }
});


}

}
```

```css
.optschecks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.opts_qty {
  width: 50px;
}

.showerror,
.opts_qty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
<div class="inprd">Please select from options for Size
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value="S - 16 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> S - 16 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">    
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" M - 17mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> M - 17mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" L- 18 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> L- 18 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
</div>
<span class="add_to_cart_container ib"><button onclick="addtocart(this.id);" name="ring" id="2617" class="add_to_cart" price="52.00" type="button">Add to basket</button></span>
```

Comment: Thank you RenzoCC, its working this way but how can I add quantity to this array, so finaly to have for example ["S - 16 mm":"1"," M - 17mm":2]
?

Comment: I have already corrected the script, you can push an object to the array in order to achieve that result.... thumbs up if it helped you..

Comment: Huge Thanks RenzoCC!

Answer (score 1):

You can create columns for multidimensional array then stringify it as JSON

Working [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b2jrc12z/)

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
    arr = [];
    var error = 0;
    var checked = 0;
    $('.p_options').each(function() {
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
         var num = $(this).next(".opts_qty").val();
            if (num !== '' && num > 0) {
              arr.push({
                Item : $(this).val(), 
                Quantity : num
              });
            }
         }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of messing about by better exploiting jQuery collections and their methods.

```
function addtocart(id) {
    var $checked = $('.p_options').filter(':checked');
    $checked.next(".opts_qty").css('background', '#fff'));
    var $badns = $checked.filter(function() {
        return !(+$(this).next(".opts_qty").val()); // anything falsy is bad
    }).next(".opts_qty").css('background', 'red');
    if($badns.length === 0) {
        var product_options = $checked.get().map(function(opt) {
            var object = {};
            object[opt.value] = $(opt).next(".opts_qty").val(); // from RenzoCC's answer
            return object;
        });
        return $.ajax({ // don't forget to return the jqXHR (promise)
            type: 'post',
            url: './shop/basket.php',
            data: { 'product':id, 'product_options':product_options},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        });
    } else {
        return $.Deferred().reject(new Error('no options selected')).promise(); // and return a rejected promise if validation fails
    }
}
```

By returning a promise, addtocart's caller is kept informed of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need an object you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yu9s6adw/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.p_options').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(1).show();
    } else $(this).next(".opts_qty").val(0).hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.optschecks {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.opts_qty {
  width: 50px;
}

.showerror,
.opts_qty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  function addtocart(id) {
    arr = {};
    var error = 0;
    var checked = 0;
    if ($('.p_options').length) {
      $('.p_options').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          var num = $(this).next(".opts_qty").val();
          if (num !== '' && num > 0) {
            if (!arr[id])
              arr[id] = []
            arr[id].push({
              item: $(this).val(),
              qty: num
            });
            checked++;
            $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', '#fff');
          } else {
            $(this).next(".opts_qty").css('background', 'red');
            error++;
          }
        }
      });
      alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
    if (error < 1) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./shop/basket.php",
        data: {
          "product": id,
          'product_options': arr
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert('success');
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<div class="inprd">Please select from options for Size
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value="S - 16 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> S - 16 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" M - 17mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> M - 17mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
  <label class="optschecks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=" L- 18 mm" name="options[]" class="p_options" data="2617"> L- 18 mm
    <input type="number" min="0" class="opts_qty" value="" name="opts_qty[]">
  </label>
</div>
<span class="add_to_cart_container ib"><button onclick="addtocart(this.id);" name="ring" id="2617" class="add_to_cart" price="52.00" type="button">Add to basket</button></span>
```